# Protect Nginx directory recursively

Tags: nginx, web

How can I protect all files and other directorys in a specific directory (-> recursively) in Nginx so they can't be accessed from the web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deny access to *locations* with a specific prefix. `nginx` resolves  locations to directory paths by using the value of the `root` or `alias` directive.

The prefix `location` with the `^~` modifier takes highest precedence and can therefore be used to deny access to specific parts of the hierarchy:

```
location ^~ /secret { deny all; }
location ^~ /secret { return 404; }
```

The above will return a 403 or 404 error response to any URI beginning with `/secret`.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why the ^~ specifier?

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie It forces the precedence to be above a regex location. Otherwise `/secret/path.php` would not be protected by the above rules.

Comment: That is false unless you have some other rules with a longer match on /secret/path.php

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie `/secret/path.php` matches `location ~ \.php$` and `location /secret`. The first takes precedence because *any* matching regex location takes precedence over a prefix location (unless the `^~` modifier is specified for the latter).

Comment: I get that but there was no mention of the php thingie location in the question.

Comment: @FlorinAsăvoaie Understood. My answer to your original question was ambiguous. I used the example for illustrative purposes only.